# Infinite Rainbow Circle Loop

Tags: after-effects

I was wondering if anyone can think of a way of recreating this infinite rainbow circle loop in After Effects
https://giphy.com/gifs/loop-rainbow-unicorn-l0LIYv9tJFIVHxF5u

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to achieve this effect. I will try to propose a flexible one:

Create a new circular shape layer and choose your first color. Open the scale and add keyframes scaling the layer from 1% to 1000%. Choose the distance between your keyframes to set the speed.

Next, duplicate that layer and choose your next color. Repeat this for as many colors as you like (your example used six). If you now offset each layer a little bit by shifting it to the right (so that it starts later), starting from the lowest layer going up, you will see that the circles overlap and form these colorful circles. The more you shift the layers to the right, the thicker the rings will be.

Now, select all layers and pre-compose them. Duplicate your precomp twice and shift it to the right so that the animation continues. Timing this offset right will result in a loopable animation. Try to find two frames that look the same, set them as your IN and OUT and render the sequence. This should result in a loopable sequence.